# How to change rule-based Layer Styles all at once in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, scale, rule-based

Let's say I have a layer with buildings which is only shown when the scale is higher than 1:10000. When the scale is higher than 5000, I want them to show its function color (retail, residential, ...) and otherwise remain grey.
I found the option to do that in **Layer-Properties > Style > rule-based**, either by typing in the scale in the **Min. scale** column or by multiselecting the attributes and then clicking **Refine current rules** where I can enter a scale value.
[image: Min. scale can be entered manually, but in more than one instance at once. (?)]

Is there no other possibility to change the scale or appearance of the selected lines than going through them one-by-one?

Answer (score 3):

You can save the layer style as an sld and open the style in a text editor. Just copy and replace the values you want. But remember that sld does not keep all the qgis symbology. It is not 1 to 1.

If you are confortable with editing text file then you will just need to search and replace the scale.